# Catch a native memory corruption bug on user devices

Tags: android, linux, assembly, arm64

Android app, Java/NDK/C++. I have very strong evidence that I have a memory corruption bug somewhere in the native parts - a variable that shouldn't change for the lifetime of the app does change. I don't have repro steps, only crash reports from user devices.

Question, can one leverage the CPU's built-in debug facilities to get the app to signal the moment data corruption happens? It'd be OK to limit that to ARM64 devices, since that's what the majority of user devices runs. AArch64 has debug registers that enable hardware watchpoints, but are those accessible from userland code? If not, is there an API/syscall for writing them?

Comment: debug registers are in EL1, eg not accessible from user space. Suppose you set watchpoint to some address by some syscall, bug happens and that would trigger interrupt and halt running process (or OS would just kill app). What are you gonna do after that especially on user device?

Comment: Just a note that there should be syscalls to set debug registers, otherwise gdb, ptrace, etc would not work

Comment: I'd assume the debug registers, just like the general purpose kind, are effectively set on per process basis, and are restored during user/kernel transitions and task switches.

Comment: Debug registers are kinda of generic register, they all described in ARMv8 technical reference manual. But commonly they are not affected by context switching (well, strictly speaking that depends on what particular OS doing, but I would not expect that to be commonly a part of context switching). Breakpoints/Watchpoints are configurable and on top of memory address, also set extra conditions to fire interrupt. One of condition is to match current process id, so not to stop other apps.